# Philips 47PFS7109/12 HDMI blinking

Tags: hdmi, tv

I have a Philips 47PFS7109/12 TV and want to connect it to PC. My PC has NVIDIA Geforce GTX 560 graphics card with HDMI slot. When I connect HDMI cable to TV (tried HDMI 1-4) I can see my desktop on TV for a second, the it goes black for a second. This blinking loop repeats. I am sure HDMI cable is fine - I had success setting up my TV to display PC content once, but I have no idea how.
Can you guide me how to debug and fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what input settings you have on the TV? if so then the only issue could be the resolution settings on the PC itself which is not compatible with the TV.

Comment: Resolution is fine, I have 1920x1080p on TV, same on PC. What do you mean about input settings?

Comment: i.e. is your TV set on the HDMI input setting, not "AV" for example.

Comment: oh, yes, definitely. Tried that on all 4 HDMI ports and selected them as sources.

Comment: I guess it could possible be the HDMI cable, I dont see hoe it could be a software or hardware issue that we have not mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the same TV and Xiaomi Mi Tv 4k.

I solved it by reducing from 60p to 30p and keeping 4K on Xiaomi. Also I switched to auto on display zoom setting of TV.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I had the exact same issue on a new Philips Ambilight 75PUS7855 (2021 model) TV when using Sky Q. Picture was absolutely fine when using the 'in house' apps such as Netflix and Alexa and also fine using the exact same HDMI port connected to a PS4 but as soon as I switched to Sky the picture would constantly flicker. On for a split second, then off, then on, and would just repeat. Tried various HDMI cables and even had Sky send a replacement box without success. Just this morning I performed a complete reinstallation of the TV itself (using the reinstallation option within settings) and this has completely resolved the issue.
I hope this helps anyone else with similar issues.
Kind regards
Ed